# Ubuntu (Unity) opens click on USB stick icon with VS Code

Tags: ubuntu, usb, visual-studio-code

I have the strange issue that when i plug in a USB stick, and click on the Icon in the taskbar, it opens the contents with VS Code.

[image]
[image]

How can i change that back to the default "nemo" application?
I somewhere read that this has something to do with a mime-type association "application/octet-stream" & VS Code.

---

EDIT:
As pointed out by @Destroy666, checking the `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop` content (mimetype):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --unity-launch %F
Icon=vscode
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=TextEditor;Development;IDE;
#MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;application/x-code-workspace;
MimeType=text/plain;application/x-code-workspace;
Actions=new-empty-window;
Keywords=vscode;

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
Name=New Empty Window
Name[de]=Neues leeres Fenster
Name[es]=Nueva ventana vacía
Name[fr]=Nouvelle fenêtre vide
Name[it]=Nuova finestra vuota
Name[ja]=新しい空のウィンドウ
Name[ko]=새 빈 창
Name[ru]=Новое пустое окно
Name[zh_CN]=新建空窗口
Name[zh_TW]=開新空視窗
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --new-window %F
Icon=vscode
```

There was a promising hint ("inode/directory"), but removing it, and restarting did not changed anything.

Issue still exists.

Comment: Did you check what's in VSCode `.desktop` file https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored? E.g. mentioned octet-stream MIME

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, it looked promising, because there was a `inode/directory` mimetype set. But after removing it and even restarting the pc, it still opens it with vscode. Added the `code.desktop` content.

Comment: What about the rest listed here? https://askubuntu.com/a/1163724/1049683